# i have an error when trying to download numpy on mac, what did i do wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, installation

[this is not the full capture but this is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di6MN.png)

I tried pip install numpy, pip3 install numpy but it says 'found candidate' cannot...:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWojF.png)

Comment: i found the answer, it is deleting you old version of python and downloading the new one.

Comment: Is the last paragraph the answer? If so, remove it from the question and post it as an answer instead.

Comment: yes it is, delete it by just moving all the python 3.9 files to trash not anything else

Comment: yes it is   just delete python 3.9 files from application and all files like documents, application, .. to TRASH

Comment: ANSWER: if that happens to you upgrade your python I was at python 3.9:
delete python 3.9
and I just deleted some things that were in like the venv ( the pip) and it worked.

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer. The answer box is below.